# Send a function as argument using FnMut

Tags: function, rust, arguments

In the following Rust code, how can I pass **objfn()** as argument in **ga_optimizer()**, knowing that **objfn()** must mutate the **self** object and returns f64 value.

Firstly, I create the Neuralnet structure:

```
pub struct Neuralnet {
    pub weights: Vec<f64>,
}
```

The Trainer struct use the previous Neuralnet struct, and calls the ga_optimizer() function bellow:

```
pub struct Trainer {
    neuralnet: Neuralnet,       
}

impl Trainer {
    pub fn do_learning(&mut self) {    
        let final_learn_err = ga_optimizer(&mut self, &mut self.objfn());        
    }

    fn objfn(&mut self, genome: &Vec<f64>) -> f64 {  
        self.neuralnet.update_weights(&genome); 
        let learn_error = self.learning_error(); 
    }

    fn learning_error(&mut self) -> f64 {
        let learn_error =0.0f64;    
          ....
        learn_error
    }
}
```

The trainer calls the ga_optimizer defined as following by using FnMut :

```
pub fn ga_optimizer(
    trainer: &mut Trainer,
    fobj: &mut dyn for<'r, 's> FnMut(&'r mut Trainer, &'s Vec<f64>) -> f64
) -> f64
{ 
   ....
}
```

How can I transform the **objfn** to closure ??. If this method doesn't work, there is another ?

Comment: Are you just looking for `ga_optimizer(&mut self, Trainer::objfn)` ?

Comment: ...or `ga_optimizer(self, |trainer| trainer.objfn())`

Comment: Also note that you can just pass `self` to `ga_optimizer`, you don't need `&mut self`, which creates an `&mut &mut Trainer`. (It still compiles because Rust's auto-dereferencing strips away the unneeded reference.)

Comment: Yes, I look to ga_optimizer(&mut self, Trainer::objfn). ie, how I can send the function **Trainer::objfn()** as argument, and **Trainer::objfn()** can modify self.

Comment: Also, the **ga_optimizer()** is out of struct **Trainer**.